# My metamask was hacked. How to safely remove my staked tokens?

Tags: metamask, cryptography

Yesterday my metamask was hacked. It happened when I was adding metamask to a reformatted laptop. My working theory is that I downloaded an illegal copy of metamask from chrome and that stole my funds. My question regards what happens next as I still have staked tokens associated with that wallet.

Interestingly they didnt steal all the funds from my wallet. They only stole tokens when I interacted with that token (actually when I added a custom token name to metamask the funds disappeared). In other words when I added AIOZ as a custom token to the metamask wallet the funds were actually diverted to the thief's account. The funds that I didnt interact with were not stolen. These included everything in the etherium part of the wallet and also the bsc tokens such as BNB with no intereaction.

Before realising what had happened (but after the tokens were stolen) I also noticed that there was some issues with the connection between metamask and projects. Maybe this also suggests that the metamask wallet was a fake download.

After realising the theft I turned off the laptop and went onto a PC that already had a proper copy of metamask on it. I was able to unstake some tokens (a small number to see that the result would be) and was able to then move these tokens to a new secure metamask wallet (I will be finding a new more secure home as soon as possible). I then gradually unstaked all my other tokens and removed them to the secure wallet in manageable blocks in case a bot or human interferred.

My ongoing issue is with three other tokens that are staked with vesting periods. One has a 7 day vesting period. The others 14 days and 1 month. If they could be unstaked now I could remove them as with the other tokens. But is it possible in the next 7 days the theives will see that the bot did half of the job and then manually try to access the tokens? If the laptop if off will they have access still? I am keeping a small amount of tokens in the wallet to monitor to see if there is any more activity.

And what to do with the staked vested tokens? Do I unstake them and and just pray that after 7 days I am the fastest to transfer them out?

They got about 15% of my portfolio. I am just happy that it was not worse. It could have been everything I guess. Try explaining that to the wife! I remember when I started that I was told exchanges are not secure and tokens should be kept in wallets. To be honest I feel my safest tokens are being stored exchanges with 2fa.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You may be interested in [this article, which explains how you can recover staked tokens in a hacked account](https://blog.mycrypto.com/how-to-beat-an-ethereum-based-sweeper-and-recover-your-assets/).

Comment: Hi! In addition to the article from MyCrypto that Morten linked, MyCrypto is currently running a service (for a 10% charge) that will help you recover assets - the details are in the article linked.